# Sortable table jQuery

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to order by name of first column even row in my DataTable. How can I modify this code?

```js
oTable_aziende = $('#table_aziende').dataTable({
  "bJQueryUI": true,
  //"sScrollY": 200,
  //"bPaginate": false,
  "bFilter": true,
  "bStateSave": true,
  "oLanguage": {
    "sUrl": "../js/dataTables.italian.txt"
  },
  "aoColumns": [
    null,
    null,
    { "bSortable": true },
    { "bSortable": false }
  ],
  "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
  "fnDrawCallback": function(o) {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
  },
  "aaSorting": [[2, "desc"]]
  //"bRetrieve": true
});
```

Comment: Sorting is set by `aaSorting`. If you want to order by the first column try `"aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc" ]]`

Comment: ok if i want sort even rows on first column?

Comment: ... you want to only sort the even rows? That doesn't make sense

Comment: i have a problem because , the even row have different content

Answer (score 0):

You need to first allow sorting for the column  "**aoColumns**". set **bSortable** for that column to **true**. Then in **aaSorting** you set default sorting direction for the sorting.

visit this link for full documentation on column sorting http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns

```
"aoColumns": [
  { "bSortable": false },
  { "bSortable": true},
  { "bSortable": false },
  { "bSortable": true},
  { "bSortable": false },
]
```

the length of the array in aoColumns must be equal to the number of columns in the original HTML table. Use 'null' where you wish to use only the default values.

hence if you want to disable or enable sorting for even or uneven columns you have to state it explicitly in aoColumns. In the above example I have disabled sorting for uneven columns and enabled sorting for even columns.

i hope that is what you are trying to achive

Comment: I don't understand how can i sort uneven rows .

Comment: @FlavioTorre i have edited and added an example check it out if it meets what you want to do